# Why Autowiring failed in Spring Boot App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm getting an exception like this :

> Description:
>
> Field ss in com.example.controllers.StrainController required a bean
>   of type 'com.example.services.StrainService' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.services.StrainService'
>   in your configuration.

Proper annotations are there (component scan + stereotype). I tried using @EntityScan, but it didn't work.

Here's my controller code :

```
@RestController
public class StrainController {

@Autowired
private StrainService ss;

    @GetMapping(value = "/strains")
    @ResponseBody 
    public List<Strain> findAll() {
        return ss.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/strains/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Strain> findById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
         Strain m = ss.findById(id);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(m);
    }

    @PostMapping("/strain")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Strain> save(@RequestBody Strain m) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(ss.save(m));
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/strain")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Strain> deleteByName(@RequestBody String name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ss.deleteByName(name));
    }

}
```

**Update:**

Console now outputs this after changing package on Component Scan:

Consider defining a bean named `entityManagerFactory` in your configuration.

AppClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")

public class WeedepediaApplication{



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(WeedepediaApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class StrainService {    

@Autowired
private StrainRepository dao;

public Strain save(Strain s){                   
    return dao.save(s);     
}

public void delete(Strain s){
     dao.delete(s);
}

public Strain findById(int id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
}
public List<Strain> findAll() {
    return dao.findAll();
}
public Strain findByName(String name) {
    return dao.findByName(name);
}
public int findIdByName(String name) {
    return dao.findIdByName(name);
}
public Strain deleteByName(String name) {
    return dao.deleteByName(name);
}
public List<Strain> findAllByStrainType(String name){
    return dao.findAllByStrainType(name);
}
public boolean existStrainByName(String name) {
    return dao.existStrainByName(name);
}
```

Project structure :

[image]

Comment: Show us your `xml` or Controller code.

Comment: okay I made an edit with controller code

Comment: What about `StrainService`, you also need to show its code, and didn't you check the @ComponentScan package, is it include the service package?

Comment: Check your `StrainService` whether be injected into Spring Container or not

Comment: Add the screenshot of the project structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle that kind of problems, if I were you, I would check it by following steps.

1. Checking the classpath, make sure that the implementation class of StrainService does included in it. You can review project's dependencies configuration, check whether the dependency which has implementation class exists or not, check if it included with the correct version that does has the implementation in it.
2. Checking to make sure that the package of StrainService implementation class does will be scanned by SpringBoot. If you haven't configured your own component scan packages like through @ComponentScan annotation, just check whether StrainService implementation classes's package are nested in the one that the main method Class has, as SpringBoot project will scan all packages beneath that the one main method Class located in.
3. There are numbers of way to define a spring bean, like A xml file, @Bean, other annotation like @Component or @Service or whatever else. Checking the bean defination 
   accroding to the way you chosen to make sure that it is declared properly.